# Flutter: Remove item for a list reflect another list

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I have the following flutter code,
I have a list, let's call it `list1`, and I am coping the value of this list to another list `list2`.

When I remove an element from `list1`, it's automatically removed from `list2`!

There is a minimal code that reproduce the issue.
I couldn't understand this strange behavior, could someone explain it to me?

What I want to do is remove an item form `list1` but keep `list2` as it is.

This is the code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(EmptyFile());

class EmptyFile extends StatefulWidget {
  final list1 = ["1", "2", "3"];
  EmptyFile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _EmptyFileState createState() => _EmptyFileState(list1);
}

class _EmptyFileState extends State<EmptyFile> {
  List<String> list1 ;
  List<String> list2 = [];

  _EmptyFileState(this.list1) {
    list2 = list1;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Example App'),
            ),
            body:
            Container(
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  print("list1.last ${list1.last}"); // the result is: list1.last 3
                  list2.remove("3");                 // here I delete from list2 (list TWO)
                  print("list1.last ${list1.last}"); // the result is: list1.last 2 . Here an item from list ONE has been deleted!!!
                },
                child: Text('delete last Item'),
              ),
            )
        ));
  }
}
```

You can run the code online from here: https://dartpad.dev/81d0a66ac7c46258df7847fdc7a10e96?null_safety=true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, dart copy the lists by reference.
So, to copy the values of a list to another list, use the following code:

```
list2  = List.from(list1);
```

instead of:

```
list2 = list1;
```

Answer (score 0):

By this

```
list2 = list1;
```

you are not actually making a copy of `list1`. It is the same list being assigned to `list2` too.

So you need to change to this.

```
list2 = [...list1];
```

Answer (score 0):

This same issue was happend with me. i get nested object data from api with help of GetX statemanagement.

the accepted answer was given by **[Hasan Mhd Amin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2609219/hasan-mhd-amin)** was absolutly right.
but in nested object (Nested List of List) is was not work as needed.

Look out MyCode

```
  List<BrandWithModel> original = [];
  List<BrandWithModel> selectedModels = [];

  // controllers
  final generalController = Get.find<GeneralController>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
      (_) {
        if (generalController.isRefreshForBrandWithModel.value) {
          generalController.brandWithModel(brandIDs: [3, 4]).then(
            (value) => initValues(),
          );
        } else {
          initValues();
        }
      },
    );

    super.initState();
  }

  void initValues() {
    original = List<BrandWithModel>.from(generalController.models);
    selectedModels = List<BrandWithModel>.from(generalController.models);

    // remove model from selectedModels
    selectedModels.forEach(
      (element) {
        element.model.clear();
      },
    );

    if (mounted) setState(() {});
  }
```

When i remove data from selectedModels this will also removed from original.

After deep research i found this.

```
    /*
   * => When you create a new list using List<BrandWithModel>.from(generalController.models),
   * it creates a new list object, but the individual elements within the list are still references to the same objects in memory.
   * Therefore, modifying an element in selectedModels will also affect the corresponding element in original because they are essentially the same object.

   * =>  If you want to have separate lists with independent data,
   *   you need to create new instances of BrandWithModel objects for selectedModels.
   *   One way to achieve this is by creating a deep copy of each element when initializing the selectedModels list.
   *   Here's an example of how you can modify the initValues() method to create a deep copy
    */
```

there for i found solution as below

```
//Used this 

    selectedModels = generalController.models
        .map(
          (model) => BrandWithModel.fromJson(   // json to modelmethod
            model.toJson(),                     // model to json method
          ),
        )
        .toList();
// instead of
  selectedModels = List<BrandWithModel>.from(generalController.models);

//  remain are same as above.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use **spread** operation:

```
list2 = [...list1];
```

That should allow any iterable to copy the values instead of using the reference.